# Remote debugging in apache ant and eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache, ant

What is the remote debugging command for ant? I am using eclipse.

Comment: Why not a real question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add jpda settings to ANT_OPTS on the machine where you want the Ant process to be debugged.

In Linux, you can just execute

```
export ANT_OPTS=$ANT_OPTS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y
```

and the following Ant builds will be ran in debug mode and WAIT for debugger to connect before execution.

In Windows you can also do the similar thing, maybe `set ANT_OPTS=%ANT_OPTS` or something.

And then, connect to the ip address and port 8000 (this is the value that you set in the jpda setting: `address=8000`, and you can set it to any available port) with the debugger.

I am not using Eclipse so I can't tell you where to find the place to connect to the ant process.